# Need help location sprint rendere in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hello,
I am 13 years old and trying to learn unity 3d from https://www.raywenderlich.com/11409307-introduction-to-unity-2d tutorial. I could not locate the sprint renderer as mentioned in the directions in the article "Click the LanderFeet GameObject located under the Lander GameObject. Then, click the small circle icon next to the Sprite field in the Sprite Renderer component properties"

Can anyone help me know what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I think you are supposed to create a gameobject in the scene called LanderFeet that is below the ship itself so as to attach the sprite renderer component to that gameObject and after attack the feet sprite to the sprite renderer so that they're rendered in the scene

Comment: Considering the issues with the post, upvoters should perhaps take a refresher of [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have the "**lander-feet**" asset selected.

Instead, you need to select the **"LanderFeet" GameObject** which you can find after clicking the **grey triangle** beside the "**Lander**" GameObject in Hierarchy.

[The yellow arrow points to where you need to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNMwr.png). This will show all the child GameObjects of a GameObject. Check the Parenting section [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Hierarchy.html) for more information.